# include requirements.txt file inside yml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, virtualenv, conda

When defining a venv using .yml file in conda, is there a way to include a Requirements.txt file inside it? normally after setting and activating the environment, one would use "pip install -r Requirements.txt" to install packages specified inside the .txt file. Is there a way to include this process inside the .yml file?

```
env.yml file:
```

`name: my_venv
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - certifi=2018.8.13=py36_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - python=3.6.6=hea74fb7_0
  - setuptools=40.0.0=py36_0
  - vc=14.1=h0510ff6_3
  - vs2015_runtime=15.5.2=3
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - pip:
       -r Requirements.txt
prefix: C:\Anaconda3\envs\my_venv`

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is that if you install the requirements file into an environment, and then do `conda export`, it will record all the dependencies from pip.